# Convert the string "8:00" into the minutes (integer value)

Tags: java, string, csv, integer

I'm reading the data from CSV file. One of the fields is the time in the format H:mm, i.e. "8:00". How to convert this string value into the minutes (integer value), i.e. 8:00 = 8*60 = 480 minutes?

```
String csvFilename = "test.csv";
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
String[] row = null;
csvReader.readNext(); // to skip the headers
int i = 0;
while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
    int open = Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
}
csvReader.close();
```

Comment: Are you reading `8:00` as an `int`?

Comment: If you don't want to **parse it by yourself** (index of ":" and two Integer.parseInt(), **did you try** it???) you may use (especially if you work with dates) **JodaTime** with its Interval class...

Comment: @devnull: yes,but obviously it's impossible. that's why I opened this thread.

Comment: Since Java 8 (which came out 6 months after this question was asked) you should use the `Duration` class for a duration of hours and minutes. For parsing your stirng like `8:00` there are some good suggestions under [this similar question: Java 8 Time API: how to parse string of format “mm:ss” to Duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642495/java-8-time-api-how-to-parse-string-of-format-mmss-to-duration).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to convert `String` to `Date`. And then `java.util.Calendar` to extract hours and minutes.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date = sdf.parse("8:00");
cal.setTime(date);

int mins = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)*60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
    String str = "8:10";
    int minutes=0;
     String[] arr= str.split(":");
    if(arr.length==2){
        minutes=Integer.parseInt(arr[0])*60+Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write something like this to convert into int

```
public int convertToMin(String hrmin) {
String[] tokens = hrmin.split(":");
int minutes = 0;
for (int i = tokens.length; i > 0; i--) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i - 1]);
    if (i == 1) {
        minutes += 60 * value;
    }
    else {
        minutes += value;
    }
  }
  return minutes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        String str = "8:20";
        int ans = (Integer.parseInt(str.split(":")[0])* 60)+Integer.parseInt(str.split(":")[1]);
        System.out.println("Answer = "+ans);
```