# How to find Difference between to time durations in java?

Tags: java

Please Help  me on this.

I had two duration times in string format:
Ex: "10" and "0.30"(actually there are in minutes)

I parsed those values Double and find the find the difference?

But I am getting the  output as 9.7 which is wrong
I want it as 9.30.. Please suggest

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you parse "0.30" to a dobule, it is interpreted as "zero point three". Ten minus "zero point three" is "nine point seven". So you will have to try a different approach

Comment: You could do some sophisticated stuff with `Calendar` and `Date`. However, in this example, it should be sufficient to convert the time into *seconds* (`int seconds = minutes*60;`), compute the difference in seconds, and afterwards convert the result back to minutes. EDIT: You should clarify whether `0.3` should mean "0.3 minutes" or "30 seconds". You have to adjust your parsing process according to this

Comment: take look at JodaTimer apis. do you want difference in minutes only?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Joda-Time Library.Use the `Period` class from which you can get the difference between two times in terms of hours and minutes.For example refer the second answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the double into minutes, Here is the link that can help you [Convert the string "8:00" into the minutes (integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656857/convert-the-string-800-into-the-minutes-integer-value).