# Java 8 Time API: how to parse string of format “mm:ss” to Duration?

Tags: datetime, java-8

I tried to use DateTimeFormatter for it, but not found way.
Duration.parse("") only use special format.

Comment: How about something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403851/parsing-time-strings-like-1h-30min?

Comment: The problem is I have to use java.time.Duration class, not joda time classes.

Comment: I found way to parse string to TemporalAccessor, may be there is a way get from it Duration?

Comment: Can you make use of DateTimeFormatter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can parse the String yourself and reformat it into the format required by `Duration`

```
String value = ... //mm:ss
String[] fields = value.split(":");
return Duration.parse(String.format("P%dM%sS", fields[0], fields[1]));
```

Comment: I wanted to use some of facilities of java 8, because format can be changed later, but now it fits. Thanks, dkatzel.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer guides in the right direction but it has the following problems which may be difficult for a beginner to figure out and correct:

1. It does not follow the [correct format of `Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--) which starts with `PT`.
2. It should use `%s` instead of `%d` for `fields[0]` as `fields[0]` is of type, `String`.

After correcting these two things, the return statement will become

```
return Duration.parse(String.format("PT%sM%sS", fields[0], fields[1]));
```

An alternative to splitting and formatting can be to use [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) as shown below:

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(parseToDuration("09:34"));
        System.out.println(parseToDuration("90:34"));
        System.out.println(parseToDuration("9:34"));
        System.out.println(parseToDuration("0:34"));
        System.out.println(parseToDuration("00:04"));
        System.out.println(parseToDuration("1:2"));
    }

    static Duration parseToDuration(String value) {
        return Duration.parse(value.replaceAll("(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2})", "PT$1M$2S"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT9M34S
PT1H30M34S
PT9M34S
PT34S
PT4S
PT1M2S
```

The regex, `(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})` has two [capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html): group(1) is specified with `$1` and group(2) is specified with `$2` in the replacement string. Each capturing group has `\d{1,2}` which specifies [1 to 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) [digit(s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, java 8 doesn't provide any facility for custom duration parsing.

You should to do it "manually". For example (an efficient way) :

```
import static java.lang.Integer.valueOf;

import java.time.Duration;

public class DurationParser {
    public static Duration parse(String input) {
        int colonIndex = input.indexOf(':');
        String mm = input.substring(0, colonIndex);
        String ss = input.substring(colonIndex + 1);
        return Duration.ofMinutes(valueOf(mm)).plusSeconds(valueOf(ss));
    }
}
```