# Parsing a Duration String in Kotlin

Tags: android, parsing, kotlin, duration

I'm working on a Android application and I need to parse a duration string of this form "00:00:00.000" (Ex: "00:00:38.47" or "00:03:27.11").

My final goal is to convert this string into a double of total seconds with milliseconds to get a progression percent.

I already looked into SimpleDateFormatter, but I'm having some issue understanding how it works or how I'm supposed to use it.

I've tried this:

```
val timeString = "00:01:08.83"
val df = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS")
df.parse(timeString)?.seconds!!.toFloat() // Returns 8.00, I want to have 68.83 for this example string
```

So is there a simple/efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to convert a string (HH:MM:SS) to a duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257641/java-how-to-convert-a-string-hhmmss-to-a-duration) And/or of [Java 8 Time API: how to parse string of format “mm:ss” to Duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642495/java-8-time-api-how-to-parse-string-of-format-mmss-to-duration) There are more questions like it, please search.

Comment: I've searched before asking my question, but I couldn't find a definitive answer to my (specific ?) question, current accepted answer isn't in your proposed duplicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  val time = LocalTime.parse("00:01:08.83", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SS"))

  println(time.toSecondOfDay())
  println(time.toNanoOfDay())
  println(time.toNanoOfDay().toFloat() / 1_000_000_000)
```

Output:

```
68
68830000000
68.83
```

Comment: Looks great, but do we have a built-in constant for this 1 billion ? Random constant value isn't good for my health :D

Comment: There is one, but it has package visibility in LocalTime... The good news is that the number of nanoseconds within a second will not change soon :-)

Comment: Note that this works only if hours component is less than 24.

Comment: A `LocalTime` is a time of day. For a duration you want a `Duration` object. Using one for the other is not correct is very likely to confuse those reading your code.

Comment: That's a good point, but looking at your answer, using a duration looks way more annoying that using this. It's only one of code that can be easily commented

Comment: Using the `float` type may [introduce mathematical inaccuracies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). Better to use the class built for the purpose of representing a span of time unattached to the timeline, [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html), as seen in the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58680750/642706).

Answer (score 4):

### java.time.Duration

As shown in the linked questions there are several ways to do this. I am afraid that there isn’t one objectively best way.

You should most probably use a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your duration.

Unfortunately there isn’t a way to parse your string directly into a `Duration`. My preference is for modifying your string into [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, the format that the `Duration` class knows how to parse. I trust you to translate my Java code into even more beautiful Kotlin code.

```
    String timeString = "00:01:08.83";
    String isoDurationString = timeString
            .replaceFirst("(\\d+):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}(?:\\.\\d+)?)", "PT$1H$2M$3S");
    Duration dur = Duration.parse(isoDurationString);
    System.out.println(dur);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> PT1M8.83S

The regular expression is powerful but hard to read. The round brackets denote groups that I want to keep in the modified string; I refer to them as `$1` etc. in the replacement string. `(?:\\.\\d+)` is a *non-capturing* group, one that I don’t need to use in the replacement. The `?` after the non-capturing group says that it needs not be there (so the expression matches just `00:01:08` as well).

For a percentage there are some options again. `Duration` objects can be directly multiplied by 100 and since Java 9 divided by each other. Assuming that you are not yet on Java 9, I would probably make the calculation based on milliseconds or nanoseconds (rather than seconds with a fraction). For example:

```
    long totalMilliseconds = dur.toMillis();
    System.out.println(totalMilliseconds);
```

> 68830

However to answer your question here’s how I would convert to seconds in a `float`:

```
    float totalSeconds = ((float) dur.toNanos()) / TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1);
    System.out.println(totalSeconds);
```

> 68.83

Answer (score 1):

The method `getSeconds()` that you use returns only the seconds of the parsed time and also it is deprecated.
If you can't use `LocalTime.parse()` in your Android app because it requires *API level 26*, then split the time string and parse it by multiplying each part with the appropriate factor:

```
val timeString = "00:01:08.83"
val factors = arrayOf(3600.0, 60.0, 1.0, 0.01)
var value = 0.0
timeString.replace(".", ":").split(":").forEachIndexed { i, s -> value += factors[i] * s.toDouble() }
println(value)
```

will print:

```
68.83
```

You could also create an extension function:

```
fun String.toSeconds(): Double {
    val factors = arrayOf(3600.0, 60.0, 1.0, 0.01)
    var value = 0.0
    this.replace(".", ":").split(":").forEachIndexed { i, s -> value += factors[i] * s.toDouble() }
    return value
}
```

and use it:

```
val timeString = "00:01:08.83"
val seconds = timeString.toSeconds()
println(seconds)
```