# Convert integer value into LocalDateTime

Tags: java, time, java-time, hour

I want to store time interval configuration into database like this:

```
12 hours -> 43200
24 hours -> 86400
42 hours -> 172800
72 hours -> 259200
```

But I'm not aware how to convert for example the value `86400` into LocalDateTime because I want to use this value in order to calculate time interval for SQL query.

What is the proper way to convert this value into LocaLDateTime?

Comment: Hi check if your answer is not here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458832/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-e-g-19000101-to-java-util-date Have a good day !

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `12 * 60 * 60` calculation?

Comment: Are you sure you need a `LocalDateTime` and not a [period or duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) ?

Comment: @NicholasK can you show me code example please?

Comment: @Abra yes I need LocalDateTime. Can you show me example please?

Comment: Unless, I've missed something if you get the value `86400` and you want to convert that into hours you can do `86400 / 60 / 60`

Comment: As far as I know, 12 hours is a [duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and not a date-time value.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest: In your SQL database use either a proper datatype for an amount of time, a duration, or a char holding a duration in ISO 8601 format. In Java use `Duration` (never `LocalDateTIme`).

If your database has a datatype for a duration, consider using is, though do weigh the pros and cons. It probably means that you will have to transfer duration values to and from your database as text strings, which is not ideal. Some RDBMSs claim that their `time` datatype can be used both for a time of day and for a duration, a hack, but if your database is happy to display 72 hours as `72:00` rather than `259200`, that’s definitely an advantage.

If you cannot or don’t want to use a proper datatype of your database, my second suggestion is ISO 8601 strings. The ISO 8601 format for a duration goes like `PT12H` (for 12 hours; read as a period of time of 12 hours). 72 hours can be given as `P3D` or `PT72H` (assuming that we can safely convert 72 hours into 3 days; this is not always correct). While this format looks a bit weird, I still find it more readable than `259200`. `varchar(13)` or so should suffice for your purpose.

In Java use a `Duration`. If the duration comes out of your database as `72:00`, search for how to parse that into a `Duration`, and search again for how to format it back. If it comes as `PT12H`, the `Duration` class parses that directly:

```
    String durationStringFromDb = "PT12H";
    Duration dur = Duration.parse(durationStringFromDb);
    System.out.println(dur);
```

Output:

> PT12H

The `Duration` prints back in ISO 8601 format, its `toString` method generates that. If you need the duration as seconds for some purpose:

```
    System.out.println(dur.getSeconds());
```

> 43200

Edit: Or the other way, if you’ve got a number of seconds from somewhere:

```
        int numberOfSeconds = 172800;
        Duration dur = Duration.ofSeconds(numberOfSeconds);
        System.out.println(dur);
```

> PT48H

### Links

- [Documentation of the `Duration` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).
- [Java 8 Time API: how to parse string of format “mm:ss” to Duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642495/java-8-time-api-how-to-parse-string-of-format-mmss-to-duration)
- [Parsing a Duration String in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670865/parsing-a-duration-string-in-kotlin)
- [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)
- [Formatting a Duration in Java 8 / jsr310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827047/formatting-a-duration-in-java-8-jsr310)
- [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use Duration in order to get some time interval in seconds. Can you show me if I have 172800 seconds how to convert it into Java Duration?

Comment: That’s just as trivial, @PeterPenzov. Did you try [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)? In any case I have edited.