# How to get input as a time from EditText in Android?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, android-edittext

How to get input as a time from `EditText` in Android?

I want to get time from `EditText` and want to use that time in `handler`.

**Example:**

"00:00:03" needs to be converted to "3000" milliseconds.

Any idea?

Comment: does this answer your question, in whole or in part? [Java 8 Time API: how to parse string of format “mm:ss” to Duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642495/java-8-time-api-how-to-parse-string-of-format-mmss-to-duration)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need to convert string (From edit text) to time in millisecond.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st="00:01:03";   
        LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse( st ) ;
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println(t.toSecondOfDay()*1000);
    }
```

Comment: `LocalTime` is for a time of day (or in this case: a time of the night). I suspect that the asker is rather dealing with an amount of time. If so, `LocalTime` is not the right class to use.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from your EditText

```
EditText txt = findViewById(R.id.edit);
String time = txt.getText().toString();
```

Then use LocalTime class from Java

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time);
int millis = localTime.toSecondOfDay() * 1000; //Time in milliseconds
```

Comment: `LocalTime` is for a time of day (or in this case: a time of the night). I suspect that the asker is rather dealing with an amount of time. If so, `LocalTime` is not the right class to use.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be in HH:mm:ss format as per your example, you can do something like:

```
    val time = etTime.text.toString()
    val units = time.split(":")  // will split the string to array of 3 elements
    val hours = units[0].toInt()  // 1st element
    val minutes = units[1].toInt()  // 2nd element
    val seconds = units[2].toInt()  // 3rd element
    val totalTimeInMillis =
        ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds) * 1000  // converting each unit to seconds and total sum to millis
```

This should do it. If your time is going to be in a different format for different cases, handle it accordingly. If it's too dynamic, handle it with something like `SimpleDateFormat` to always get the time in a certain format, and then you can again use the same logic. You can also define this as a helper method and reuse it at multiple places, returning millis from a given time format.